# Can i use single Google Cloud Messaging for Android api for multiple android apps?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi all i am successfully able to implement push notification in one of my android application. Now i knew that android console is only provide 25 apps in a single app.

So my question is that can i use single `Google Cloud Messaging for Android` application in my multiple android application without creating new Application in `Google Console`.?

Comment: Reason for down-voting. 
If there is no reason then it seems that you are not a good knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, yes you can. Accroding to Google's Android team,

> When you send a message, you specify a registration ID, which is
>   implicitly linked to the package name of the app + device where it was
>   generated. Only the app which requested the registration ID will
>   receive your message.

So as long as you are maintaining a unique package name for your app each registration ID will be different and you can forward the push message to that specif ID only.

Comment: There are 2 apps 1. com.test.app1 2. com.test.app2 and installed on same device with same GCM api. Then registration ID for both apps were same or different.

Comment: In that sense the id's will be different because the complete package names aren't same. I would suggest you to use a unique identifier with your package name e.g. com.test1.app1